# Getting the observable from an element in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have written the following code to get the Knockout view model observable from an HTML element but I was wondering if there was a better way to do it without knowing the observable's name?

```
var dataBinding = $(element).data('bind');
var observableName = dataBinding.substr(dataBinding.indexOf('value:')+6);
observableName = observableName.substr(0, observableName.indexOf('(')).trim();
var observable = ko.dataFor(element)[observableName];
return observable;
```

Comment: Can you explain your use-case more? Why are you trying to the get the observable, and from what code?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a more direct approach:
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/CajFz/ (fiddle was created by the knockout creator)

of note:

```
var name1Data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(ko.utils.domData.get(document.getElementById("name1"), "ko_data"));
```

the `ko.utils.domData.get` call does what you're looking for

Comment: The example requires that the binding set the `ko_data` value. So this won't work for bindings in general.